# Proving a function is continuous but unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

**Problem:**

Hi, I'm working on the following math problem:

> Suppose a set $S$ contains a sequence that converges to a point
>   $x_{0}$ that is *not* in $S$. Show that the function $f : S
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1/|x - x_{0}|$ for all $x$
>   in $S$ is continuous but unbounded.

Here is the definition of continuity that I am referring to. Note, however, that I am not using the typical $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity:

> **Definition:** A function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *continuous at the point $x_{0}$ in $D$*  provided that whenever
>   $\{x_{n}\}$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $x_{0}$, the image
>   sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}$ converges to $f(x_{0})$.

---

**My attempt:**

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $S$ that converges to the point $x_{0}$, which is not in $S$. By the definition of convergence provided, this means $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ s.t.

$$|x_{n} - x_{0}| < \epsilon$$

$\forall n \geq N$. To prove continuity at $x_{0}$, I must show that there is some index $N'$ so that $\forall \epsilon > 0$,

$$|f(x_{n}) - f(x_{0}) | < \epsilon$$

$\forall \epsilon > 0$. By our definition of $f$, I can write

$$|f(x_{n}) - f(x_{0}) | = |1/(x - x_{0}) - 1/(x_{0} - x_{0})|,$$

but the right-hand term is not defined, so I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

---

**Some additional info:**

In case it helps, this problem is part of a two-part problem. The first part of this problem asked me to show that if $S$ contains an unbounded sequence, then show that the function $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x$ for all $x$ in $S$ is continuous but unbounded. So, I can cite this fact if I want. I'm guessing that I'll have to since it's part of the same problem, but I'm not sure where that'll come into play.

Thank you to anyone who tries to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem asks to show continuity for all $x \in S$ and $x_0\not\in S$!

So if $x_n\to x$ then we have to prove that for all $\epsilon>0$,  eventually
$$|f(x_{n}) - f(x) | = \left|\frac{1}{|x_n - x_{0}|} - \frac{1}{|x - x_{0}|}\right|<\epsilon.$$ 
As regards the second part, show that there is a sequence $x_n\to x_0$ in $S$ such that , for all $M>0$,  eventually
$$|f(x_{n})| = \frac{1}{|x_n - x_{0}|}>M.$$

P.S. Note that
$$\left|\frac{1}{|x_n - x_{0}|} - \frac{1}{|x - x_{0}|}\right|=\frac{||x - x_{0}|-|(x_n-x)+(x - x_{0})||}{|x - x_{0}|\cdot|x_n - x_{0}|}\\
\leq \frac{|x_n - x|}{|x - x_{0}|\cdot ||x - x_{0}|-|x_n - x||}$$
because, by triangle inequality, $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$. Finally, given $\epsilon>0$, consider $|x-x_n|<\epsilon'$, with 
$$\epsilon'=\frac{1}{2}\min(|x-x_0|,\epsilon|x-x_0|^2).$$

Comment: Use different $\epsilon$s: you know that for  $\epsilon'>0$, $|x_n−x|<\epsilon'$ for all $n≥N$.  For $\epsilon>0$, show that $|f(x_n)−f(x)|<ϵ$ for all $n≥N$.

Comment: @stackofhay42 See my P.S.

Comment: @stackofhay42 If $x_n\to x$ the RHS in the P.S. goes to zero.

Comment: hey, sorry for bothering you again. i think what you posted shows that $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x \in S$, but not $x_{0} \not \in S$. do I need to show that it's continuous for $x_{0} \not \in S$? or does what you have sufficiently answer the question? if what you have answers the question, why does the question even mention the set having a sequence that converges to $x_{0} \not \in S$? why does that matter? thank you so much btw.

Comment: No, you don't need to to show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. $f$ is not even defined at $x_0$!! The existence of the sequence in $S$ which is convergent to $x_0$ is necessary for the second part.

Comment: Okay, got it. So, to show that it's unbounded, I can consider the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, which converges to $x_{0} \not \in S$. Then, by the Archimidean Property of $\mathbb{R}$, for any positive integer $c$, there is an index $n$ such that $|x_{n} - x_{0}| < 1/c$; or equivalently, $f(x_{n}) > c$.  Is this sufficient? I don't believe I used the fact that $x_{0}$ isn't in $S$, though

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  The fact that  $x_0$ isn't in $S$ and $x_n\not \in S$ means that $x_n\not=x_0$ and therefore $f$ can be evaluated at $x_n$.

Comment: one final question -- what is a more clear way to show that the fraction in your P.S. is strictly less than $\epsilon$? I substituted $\epsilon$ for the $|x_{n} - x|$ terms already

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$, take $\epsilon'=\frac{1}{2}\min(|x-x_0|,\epsilon|x-x_0|^2)$ and  $|x-x_n|<\epsilon'$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84479/discussion-between-stackofhay42-and-robert-z).

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not correct because $x_0\notin D$. So, it makes no sense to ask whethr $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. The function $f$ is continuous because, for instance:

- the function $x$ is continuous;
- so, $x-x_0$ is continuous;
- since the absolute value function is continuous, $\lvert x-x_0\rvert$ is continuous;
- therefore, $\dfrac1{\lvert x-x_0\rvert}$ is continuous.

And $f$ is unbounded because, if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=+\infty$.